# Ember-data model computed value, return value instead of promise

Tags: ember.js, ember-data, promise

I have ember models called `survey`, `question`, and `response`. `survey`s have multiple `question`s, which have multiple `response`s. Each `response` has an attribute `count`.

How do I set a `total_response_count` computed value in the `survey` model? In emberjs 1.0.0, the `questions` are in a DS.PromiseArray (due to the async: true), so when I return the computed value, it shows up in my template as an Object rather than a value.

I can easily access `responses` from the `question` model because `responses` are embedded in `question`. However, Ember automatically makes promises for the `questions` referenced by `survey` because {async: true}.

Survey Model:

```
App.Survey = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr('string'),
  owner_id: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  questions: DS.hasMany('question', {async:true}),

  total_responses: function() {
    var question_cb = function(prevValue, item) {
      return prevValue + item.get('total_responses');
    };

    return this.get('questions').then(function(questions){
      return questions.reduce(question_cb, 0);
    });
  }.property('questions')
});
```

Question Model:

```
App.Question = DS.Model.extend({
  survey: DS.belongsTo('survey'),

  question: DS.attr('string'),

  responses: DS.hasMany('response'),

  total_responses: function() {
    var response_cb = function(prevValue, item) {
      return prevValue + item.get('count');
    };

    return this.get('responses').reduce(response_cb, 0);
  }.property('responses')
});
```

Response Model:

```
App.Response = DS.Model.extend({
  response: DS.attr('string'),
  count: DS.attr('number'),

  question: DS.belongsTo('question')
});
```

I'm using ember-1.0.0 and ember-data 1.0 beta-2.

Comment: Can you try calling reduce directly on the `this.get('questions')` PromiseArray?

Comment: I did; it doesn't work because it tries to reduce the PromiseArray directly, and since it's an "array of length 0" it returns 0.

Comment: How about computing from both `questions` and `questions.isFulfilled`?

Comment: How would I do that? Where is the data located when the promise is fulfilled? I couldn't find it in inspect element.

Comment: Have you tried to compute the property based on `questions.@each` ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I also asked this question on [Github](https://github.com/emberjs/data/issues/1315#issuecomment-24641364), and got this response from Yehuda Katz:

You can try something like this:

```
App.Survey = DS.Model.extend({
  title: DS.attr(),
  owner: DS.belongsTo('user'),
  questions: DS.hasMany({ async:true }),

  totalResponses: Ember.arrayComputed('questions', {
    initialValue: 0,
    addedItem: function(accum, item) {
      accum += item.get('totalResponses');
    },
    removedItem: function(accum, item) {
      accum -= item.get('totalResponses');
    }
  })
});
```

When questions resolves, the addedItem callback in totalResponses will be called once for every item in the resolved array.